# PHP $_SESSION array populated in one div and empty in another

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

OK...i have something which makes no logical sense and I hope someone can point out the silly mistake I am making. I have a page in which i want the menus to change whether a user is logged in or not. I am using a session variable $_SESSION['is_logged_in] to store the logged in status. So for example, if logged out, the menu should say login. If logged in, the same menu should say logged out. Here is the code in logical pieces. I apologize in advance for all the code snippets but I want to be as clear as possible. Please help!

First, i have the main page called index.php which has some empty divs:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="header">
      <h1>My Page</h1>
      <div id="navigation">
      </div> <!-- end of navigation div -->
   </div> <!-- end if header div -->
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <div id="mainContent">
   </div><!-- end mainContent div -->
</div> <!-- end wrapper div -->
```

In this page (index.php), i have a jquery load of the navigation div on document ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
      //load the default menu
      $('#navigation').load("menu.php");
   });
</script>
```

OK...now menu.php has the following html/php:

```
<?php 
   session_start();
   include 'php/functions.php';

   //following is for debugging, you will see later where this is useful
   if (is_logged_in())
   {     
     echo "logged in value: " . is_logged_in() . "<br />"; 
     print_r($_SESSION);
   }
   else
 echo "not sure what is going on</br >";
   echo "<br />"; 
?>
  <ul id="menu" class="DropdownMenu">
     <li class="sub"><a href="#">Account</a>
        <ul>
           <?php 
              //this is where it should show one link or the other based on the value in $_SESSION
              if (is_logged_in()) { 
                echo "<li><a href=\"#\" class=\"ClickLogout\">Log Out</a></li>\n";
              } else {
                echo "<li><a href=\"#\" class=\"ClickLogin\">Log In</a></li>\n";
              } 
           ?>
        </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
```

Ok...at this point, when the page loads, on top of the menu i see the debug message "not sure what is going on here" as expected because i am not logged in yet. Then I click on the Login link and via ajax, it populates the mainContent div in the index.php:

This is in menu.php:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   var options = { 
      target:        '#mainContent',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
      success:       reloadMenu,  // post-submit callback 
      delegation:    true
   }; 

   // post-submit callback 
   function reloadMenu(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  { 
      $('#navigation').load("menu.php");
   }; 

   //set the jquery form plugin for the login form
   $('.ContentForm').ajaxForm(options);

   //load the login form in the mainContent div
   $('#wrapper').on("click", ".ClickLogin", function(e) {
      $('#mainContent').load("login.php");
   });

});
```

The above code shows that when the form is submitted, on success, the post submit callback should be re-loading the menu just like the initial load on the index.php document ready. With debugging, i do see that the it does reload it, but it never sees anything in the session variables so even though i am logged in, it still shows the Login link instead of log out.

Now, bringing it all together just to show i am not crazy, here is what is in the login.php:

```
<?php
   // start the session
   session_start();
   include 'php/functions.php';

   //this sections handles the post of the form
   $show_form = true;
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") 
   {
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];

      if (authenticate_user($email, $password)) //this will set $_SESSION variables
      {
         $show_form = false;
         echo "Congratulations " . get_user_name() . ", you are logged in <br />";

         //following is for debugging, you will see later where this is useful
         if (is_logged_in())
         {   
            echo "logged in value: " . is_logged_in() . "<br />"; 
            print_r($_SESSION);
         }
         else
            echo "not sure what is going on</br >";
      }
      else
      {
         echo "Invalid email or password. Try again <br />";
      }
   }
?>

<?php if ($show_form) { ?>
<div id="formContent">
   <h2 class="ContentHeader">Log In</h2>
   <form id="contentForm" name="registration" class="ContentForm" method="post" action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>>
      <p>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required="required">
     </p>
     <p>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required="required">
     </p>
     <p>
        <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insertLink" value="Submit It" /> 
        <input type="reset" name="cancel" id="cancel" value="Reset" />
     </p>
     <p>Forgot Password? Click <a href="#">here</a></p>
     <p>Need to Register? Click <a class="ClickRegister" href="#">here</a></p>
  </form>
```

I know it is a lot of code so i want to point out one thing. At this point, when the form is submitted, in the #navigation div, the menu.php is reloaded and in the #mainContent div, the login.php is reloaded. Both are executing this exact same code:

```
     //following is for debugging, you will see later where this is useful
 if (is_logged_in())
 {   
    echo "logged in value: " . is_logged_in() . "<br />"; 
    print_r($_SESSION);
 }
 else
    echo "not sure what is going on</br >";
```

When the page displays after the login form submit, above the menu it says "not sure what is going on" followed by "Array()", however in the mainContent, it shows "logged in value: 1" and prints out all the session values.

Just for completeness, the is_logged_in() function looks like this:

```
//return true if the current session is logged in
function is_logged_in()
{
   if (array_key_exists('is_logged_in', $_SESSION))
      return $_SESSION['is_logged_in'];
}
```

I have session_start() in both menu.php and login.php, if i didn't it gives me all sorts of other errors when trying to access the $_SESSION array.

I really hope someone can spot my mistake. Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Chck that the session cookie's value stays the same throughout all these requests. if it's changing, you're getting a new/empty session each time, which explains why your values are "vanishing" - they're still there, but in some OTHER session.

Comment: [session_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php)

Comment: Ok, now i am more confused. I just put this: echo "session id is: " . session_id() . "<br />"; in my debug session. Above the menu where it does not have the $_SESSION variables, it outputs "session id is: b4troko5177cm2cscrb3ltiur6" where as in mainContent where it prints out the $_SESSION array just fine, it shows "session id is: "

Comment: Try doing it without all the ajax/javascript.  It's getting in the way.  Just have a page that writes a integer to $_SESSION and increments it each time.  When you verified that sessions are working at all, then write the whole thing again without any ajax whatsoever.  Then add ajax until it breaks.  Then you have found the problem.

Comment: oh man...that's a heavy suggestion :(

Comment: @Kamran The only other easy thing you might be able to do is give us the contents of `authenticate_user($email, $password)`.  There may be something obvious in there.

Comment: @Kamran Also, nah it's not that big a job.  Just get rid of the javascript and use a few `includes()` instead.  You should have it up and running in no time, and it will help.

Comment: Thanks sennett...your tip on authenticate user helped me find it. So after login, i thought it would be smart to call my logout procedure and unset everything before i reset it. The logout had this:     session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    session_write_close();
    setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
    session_regenerate_id(true);
Still not sure why that showed two different session information considering both should have been populated after this code ran, but it seems to work now that i removed it! Thanks for all the quick responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question officially for closure. As mentioned in the comments above, I was destroying the session prior to setting it as part of the login. I am still not sure why that had the effect it did since both divs were loaded after the destroy/re-create but maybe there is some ajax race condition.

I am just glad it is solved and I can move on. Thanks to all for your input.